# Add matching word into list with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-2.0

How can I add all required words into a list with single line code? I want to use lambda expression but no idea how it will be used? Other solutions are also welcome. When targeting on NET 2.0, lambdas are available, but LINQ isn't. So is it possible to avoid LINQ dll add?

```
List<string> lstStr = new List<string>();
string[] objStr = new string[] { "Software", "Development", "department", "store", "Marketing" };
foreach (string objLcl in objStr)
{
    if (objLcl.Contains("o"))
    {
        lstStr.Add(objLcl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example will return an empty collection. Is that what you mean? Or did you mean `Contains("o")`?

Comment: Wha should the result look like? Currently it returns an empty collection, but I suppose you want all the words that *contain* the character `o`, don´t you?

Comment: Why do you care so much about one line? You should first be sure that the code is working as expected and is well understood. Then have a look at some Linq tutorials

Comment: Ohh, Actually I did some R&D and forget to change the code.

Comment: If you can't use LINQ, don't include LINQ as a tag. Seems rather counter-intuitive.

Comment: I removed it. #J. Steen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, with more R&D, I found a solution and its very simple.

```
lstStr.AddRange(Array.FindAll(objStr, x => x.Contains("o")));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ `Where()` method like

```
lstStr  = objstr.Where(s => s.Contains("o")).ToList();
```

Well per comment, if you want to do a case in-sensitive search you will have to  use `indexOf()` method where you can pass `StringComparison` enum value since `Contains()` has no overload which can take a `StringComparison` enum value.

```
lstStr  = objstr.Where(s => s.IndexOf("o", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                .ToList();
```

Again, in case you want to use LINQ then go for normal `foreach` loop control like

```
foreach(var s in objstr)
{
  if(s.IndexOf("o", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
      lstStr.Add(s);  
}
```

Comment: @un-lucky, that's mostly typo cause with the array values posted that wouldn't do anything

Comment: Lol now its added

Comment: @J.Steen, right but it's per OP's posted code where the array values are in lower case

Comment: If I do not want use LINQ then?

Comment: When targeting on NET 2.0, lambdas are available, but LINQ isn't. So is it possible to avoid LINQ dll add?

Comment: @jsteen, see edit in answer, hope that answer your comment

Comment: @Rahul Spot on. =)

Comment: @ Rahul, You wrote same logic with different expression :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all strings that **contain** "o":

```
lstStr.AddRange(objStr.Where(o => o.Contains("o")));
```

Comment: Sometimes I get the feeling, I'm followed by some revenge seeking Person. Same answer from Rahul, that came in later gets upvoted. Really strange

Comment: @J.Steen Why is that? Even the code OP stated as his working example won't do so? Do you want to say that OP is wrong about his assumption that his code works ;-)^^

Comment: @J.Steen Ok, given his question, you might be right :-D

Comment: When targeting on NET 2.0, lambdas are available, but LINQ isn't. So is it possible to avoid LINQ dll add?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Assuming you want to have the entries which contain "o" and not equal to "o". If not you have to change `Contains` to  `Equals` and get the expecting result.

```
string[] objStr = new string[] { "Software", "Development", "department", "store", "Marketing" };
var lstStr = objStr.Where(x => x.Contains("o")).ToList();
```

Have a look at [101 LINQ-Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for more information.

Comment: When targeting on NET 2.0, lambdas are available, but LINQ isn't. So is it possible to avoid LINQ dll add?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid extra memory allocations, the items can be removed from the source collection (no LINQ):

```
var lstStr = new List<string> { "Software", "Development", "department", "store", "Marketing" };

lstStr.RemoveAll(s => !s.Contains("o"));
```

Comment: but you directly add values into list...?

Comment: @cSharma or use list instead of array

Answer (score -1):

Below is the Linq

```
string[] objStr = new string[] { "Software", "Development", "department", "store", "Marketing" };
List<string> lstStr = objStr.Where(objLcl => objLcl.Contains("o")).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting data from database where a need to categorize row by some specific words and stored in a different table. So I want to use less coding to do that.